# Dividing lines between sections of bar plot with ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using qplot to create a stacked bar plot and would like to place a white line between the sections of each bar as the blues seem to almost blend together. I do not want to change my existing colour scheme to resolve the problem. Any ideas?

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", fill = color)
```

[image]

Comment: I would definitely change the colour scheme. If you want 7 distinct colours, use RColorBrewer package and check out display.brewer.pal(7,"Set1") - its done by science.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the argument `colour="white"` to create a white outline:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill=am, group=am)) + geom_bar(colour="white")
```

[image]

---

Here is a workaround to remove the diagonal line from the legend (inspired by a [posting on ggplot mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/vJnF9_HBqx4)). The idea is to plot the `geom_bar` twice, once suppressing the colours:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill=am, group=am)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  geom_bar(colour="white", show_guide=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I was just wondering is there any way to avoid the diagonal slash going through the legend fills?